# I would like to add javascript regexp satisfying my concerns

Tags: javascript, regex

I need following regexp such as..
the parenthesis are just to show the words

(abc) => pass
(abc ) => pass    * abc with trailing white space
(abc ..blah..) => pass   * ..blah.. means any chars containing spaces
(abcd) => fail

is there any good idea to do? 
I trimmed the string so basically the first two cases are the same
but i couldn't make it fail when (abcd) comes in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (/abc\b/im.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var doesItPass = (stringToValidate.split(" ")[0] == "abc") ? false : true;
```

Comment: isn't there any elegant way without spliting the string?

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex`:

```
/^abc\s*$/
```

Regex is the way of doing such things.

Comment: it looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: @SungsooMoon. Nope, the opening was a typo.

Comment: it looks like it works on 'aaa' also i got solved as I sovlved the problem with /^abc(\s[\w]*|)$/i

Comment: @SungsooMoon. It must start with abc and edit with 0 or more spaces?

Comment: @SungsooMoon. I updated the answer but please give all the details in the question.

Comment: i needed the word match that the first word appeared in the string must be 'abc'

Comment: sorry i thought the examples were enough to explain my question, i apologize